# FastAPI Query String Filters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

**I want all query filter fields, operators and values from query**

Query -> http://localhost:8000/user/list?take=10&skip=0&FirstName=Jhon&sort=ID|ASC&amount>=100

**the expected output is:**

```
[
{"field":take, "operator":=, "value":10},
{"field":skip, "operator":=, "value":0},
{"field":FirstName, "operator":=, "value":Jhon},
{"field":sort, "operator":=, "value":ID|ASC},
{"field":amount, "operator":>=, "value":100},
]
```

Comment: This seems to require custom parsing of a query string; have you attempted anything to parse your input string into what you're looking for? (i.e. this is not really FastAPI related expected for how to retrieve the actual query string).

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh i tried that. do you know best way to parse filter in query in FastAPI.

Comment: That would require a custom parser to do what you want - you can access the query string through `request.url.query` iirc.